Why did the author write "calls made via local, fixed lines" instead of "calls made via local fixed lines"? Why the comma?
An IELTS examiner wrote:

It is clear that calls made via local, fixed lines were the most popular type, in terms of overall usage, throughout the period shown. (I can't find the original post, but I can confirm that this site reposted the exact essay that I'd read)

I wonder why he inserted the comma between the two attributive adjectives. I don't normally see people do that. What difference does it make?

Does this answer your question? Putting a comma between adjectives

Interesting! But I'm not sure if it is the answer for my question because even without the comma, I still only interpret local fixed lines as the system used for local calls using landlines.

"Local fixed lines" means fixed lines that are local (as opposed to fixed lines that aren't local); this is a subset of all fixed lines. "Local, fixed lines" means lines that are both local and fixed; this is the intersection of local lines and fixed lines. I think the two phrasings are equivalent, and the first is more natural.

The fixed may be intended as sharpening the meaning of local. Compare His paintings are childish, sloppy and His paintings are childish, derivative. In this kind of usage, the comma essentially has the same effect as if it were replaced by phrases like by which I mean or in that [they are].
